# Batch get start arguments from textfile

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can i start a program with arguments from textfile ?

**Batch.bat**

```
@textFile = "c:\Users\Arguments.txt";
start "" "C:\Users\coffee.cmd" --join test.js --compile @textFile
```

**Arguments.txt**

```
test5.coffe 
test2.coffe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
set arg_file=textFile
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%arg_file%") do (
   set "argline=!argline! %%A"
) 
start "" "C:\Users\coffee.cmd" --join test.js --compile !argline!
endlocal
```

Comment: thanks for your great help. do you know how can i specify relative path for textfile ? tried it with pushd "%~dp0" and arg_file=.\references.txt do not work

Comment: do you have spaces in the path?Did you used `SHIFT` command in the script?

Comment: `pushd "%~dp0"` and `arg_file=.\references.txt` this will work only if the file and the script are in same directory.

Comment: yes i've started the cmd separately, its works by calling it directly, thanks again